# Flask returning wrong value from radio inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, flask

I'm trying to get value stored inside the input's variable from form.

My html file looks like this:

```
<body topmargin="200">
    <form method="post" action="translation">
        <div align="center">
            <font size="5">ქართული >> ინგლისური</font>
            <input type="radio" name="convert" value="geo">
            <br>
            <font size="5">ინგლისური >> ქართული</font>
            <input type="radio" name="convert" value="eng">
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="words" size="70">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="თარგმნა">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

and this is part of the code. Inside the try clause, I'm storing the value taken from radio button into the variable "convert" and this value should either be "eng" or "geo", but instead, it returns "on" everytime. I don't know why it is happening. This is what the website looks like: http://hgresa.pythonanywhere.com/:

```
def translation(word):
    try:
        geo_to_eng = list(dictionary.keys())[list(dictionary.values()).index(word)]
        return geo_to_eng
    except ValueError:
        return dictionary[word]

@app.route("/")
def base():
    return render_template("input.html")

@app.route("/translation", methods=["POST"])
def translate():
    word_to_translate = request.form["words"].lower()
    finished = translation(word_to_translate)

    try:
        choice = request.form["convert"]
        render = render_template("results.html", the_word=word_to_translate, translated=finished)
        print(choice)
        if choice == "eng":
            return render
        elif choice == "geo":
            return render

        return render_template("results.html", the_word=word_to_translate, translated=finished)

    except:
        return render_template("results.html", the_word=word_to_translate, translated=finished)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know how to properly debug to find the cause of a problem.

If you turn on network debugging (e.g. *inspect* in Chrome and then look at the *Network* tab), you can see that the data transmitted by the browser to the server is:

```
convert=on&words=
```

So, the value of `convert` is `"on"`. There is nothing you can do about it in Flask. The problem is in HTML.

Then, if you take a look at the source of http://hgresa.pythonanywhere.com/, you will se that it actually has this:

```
        <font size="5">ქართული >> ინგლისური</font>
        <input type="radio" name="convert">
        <br>
        <font size="5">ინგლისური >> ქართული</font>
        <input type="radio" name="convert">
```

There is no `value` in the `<input>` tags. That is why you don't get a value.

Comment: Actually, that's the older version of web app. I know that there is no value there, I put that link here to demonstrate how it looks like. And, now I understand the problem. Thanks for the help